# Running 5v and 12v strips together?

Tags: ws2812

I want to run 5v and 12v strips and halos together, i read that with the 12v strips, give 12v to the strip but the data is always 5 volts, and tie the ground to the ground of the 5v controller?

I use SP105E bluetooth controllers off ebay, and i use a 10/20a 12v to 5v buck converter to get me to 5v as i use my lights in vehicle accessories so thats why i dont have a power supply or anything.

So would i just take the 12v strip, run the +12v to the +12v then data to the data wire and tie the 12v strip ground to the 5v ground on the controller/step down converter?

Comment: They aren't a lot of addressable led strips that use 12Volt. Are you sure that's what you have. PS don't use a 12V transformer for halogen bulbs to power led strips. Those transformers don't give a nice stable 12V, as halogen bulbs don't care if the voltage fluctuates or spikes.

Comment: In electronics, 99% of the time you will need to tie all the grounds together for a common ground. So yes, the - of the 12v strip needs to be connected to the - of the 5v strip.

Comment: Yes im sure they are 12v addressable strips. i have 5v and 12v, ws2811 and ws2812b. i dont know about a halogen transformer? but im using a step down buck converter very commonly used in automotive LEDs, which is where all my led work is based, also ive never really had any stability issues with these step downs, hopefully it doesn't start.

Comment: Please explain what halos are. In my opinion a halo is a titanium protection bar for f1 racing drivers. 12v led strips are often used for aquarium lights. Sometimes they have dc-dc converters included in the strips. There is no problem with 12v and 5v led strips to the same arduino or to the same bluetooth controller, but we like to see a drawing of all the wiring. This is the arduino section. Is there a hidden arduino somewhere?

Comment: Halo is a ring, a circle, a circle of leds. There is no arduino in this setup, just the SP105e controller and the strips/circle rings. I didnt know where else to ask about 5v/12v leds and wiring other than this forum because everyone seems to use the 5v addressable LEDs which is why its in this section.


I now have wired a 5v and 12v strip together and they work, however now my issue seems to be the blue and green colors are backwards, when i select green, the 5v strip is green and the 12v is blue or vice versa, and the same when i go to blue, however red is red on both.

Comment: here is a sketch of the wiring http://i63.tinypic.com/30lcsnn.png